# C++ Does derived class could inheritance Static data member and Static Member function from Base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

C++ Does derived class could inheritance Static data member and Static Member function from Base class?

```
class Base
{
public:
    static int base1;
    static void function1() {};
protected:
    static int base2;
    static void function2() {};
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int a;
protected:
    int b;
}
```

Does `Derived` have `base1`, `base2`, and `function1` and `function2`?

If the `Derived` class has them, what's the relationship between the `protected` data and `public` data which is inherited from base class? Are they same? Or are the inheritance data and function a copy of its base class?

Answer (score 3):

The `static` members are not *inherited* but they are still *accessible*. That is, there won't be a version for the derived type, but you can still access them and it will be the same as if you access the base static members directly.
Since static data members are common for all objects.

Comment: For clarity, are non-static data members and member functions "inherited", and if so how does this differ from the "not-inherited" nature of the static ones?

Comment: @SteveJessop: That is a much harder question to answer and it requires a precise definition of what *inherited* means. The derived type *contains* an instance of the base class as a subobject, so the non-static data members are *there*, although they might or might not be available for direct use (depending on access specifiers). The difference would be that when you modify the non-static members you modify part of this object, but when you modify the static members you are modifying the Base's static members. Someone else modifies the static members of Base, the values you see will change.